# No overload for method 'InsertQuery' takes 15 arguments

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

I want to insert dummy values into data base. But it will generate an error.
The code is Given below.

```
protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        DataSet3TableAdapters.tbl_energy_reportTableAdapter state = new DataSet3TableAdapters.tbl_energy_reportTableAdapter();
        int j;
        j = state.InsertQuery(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i.ToString(), DateTime.Now.AddDays(i), i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i.ToString(), DateTime.Now.AddDays(i));
    }
}
```

Insert Query::

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_energy_report] ([Site_name], [Site_ID], [State], [Cluster], [Date], [Dg_energy_daily], [Dg_energy_cumulative], [Load_energy_daily], [Load_energy_cumulative], [mains_energy_daily], [mains_energy_cumulative], [solar_energy_daily], [solar_energy_cumulative], [Generate_date]) VALUES (@Site_name, @Site_ID, @State, @Cluster, @Date, @Dg_energy_daily, @Dg_energy_cumulative, @Load_energy_daily, @Load_energy_cumulative, @mains_energy_daily, @mains_energy_cumulative, @solar_energy_daily, @solar_energy_cumulative, @Generate_date)
```

Comment: Show your InsertQuery function here

Comment: @ManishParakhiya : Insert query already given above. Please check that one.

Comment: `DataSet3TableAdapters.tbl_energy_reportTableAdapter` doesn't look like any known library, so I'd have to say it has no overload with 15 parameters.

Comment: @vipintp show method definition for `InsertQuery`

Answer (score 1):

this Error is Due to difference in No of Parameters pass in definition of method and calling

like in Your method you may pass 15 parameters
and in definition may be only 14 parameters

```
state.InsertQuery(para1,para2)  //calling


   public int InsertQuery(para1)  //definition
{

}
```